деепричастный оборот или сравнительный?
"...выступила из-за поворота взобравшаяся на холм маленькая деревянная церквушка, словно годами-веками поджидая самого Исаака Ильича Левитана".
Будет здесь причастный оборот или сравнительный? Слово "словно" меня смущает, а сталкиваюсь с таким впервые

Правильно:
...выступила из-за поворота взобравшаяся на холм маленькая деревянная церквушка, словно годами-веками поджидая самого Исаака Ильича Левитана.
Пояснение
Это деепричастный оборот, к которому относится союз-частица  словно.
Слово словно в данном случае является союзом, который может присоединяться к различным синтаксическим конструкциям, в том числе к деепричастному обороту.
Пример с причастным оборотом.
Словарь
  СЛОВНО, I. союз (в придат. сравнит.). Как, точно, будто. 
  Крадётся, с. кошка. Несётся, с. угорелый. Смотрит, с. сыч. 
  // Выражает условно-предположительное сравнение в зн.: как 
  будто, как если бы. Мотор урчит, с. сердится. Ты с. с луны 
  свалился. 
  II. частица. Разг. Указывает на неуверенность, 
  предположительность высказывания в зн.: как будто. Ты с. 
  чем-то огорчён? Меня с. знобит. Он с. что-то сказал? 
  Словно как, в зн. союза. (в придат. сравнит.). Разг. 
  Точно, как будто. Звук высокий, словно как поёт кто-то.

Справочник
  СЛОВНО, союз и частица...Она вдруг закружилась и на глазах 
  у всех словно юркнула в землю. Н. Тэффи, Когда рак 
  свистнул. И все они, втроем, живут в одной большой 
  комнате, чрезвычайно пустой и словно бы необжитой. А. 
  Битов, Сад. 

